# Dependency property causing StackOverflowException

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8.1

Example xaml code on the page which causes `StackOverflowException`.
If remove `MyProperty="{Binding ElementName=SourceFlyout}"` from second element,
it's ok. `MyProperty` is an attached property. `AdvancedBehavior` is the simplest behavior class and the bug is easily reproduced. 
`MyProperty` is an empty attached or dependency property with no logic inside. What happens?

```
<ListPickerFlyout x:Name="SourceFlyout">
    <helpers:XamlExtention.Behaviors>
        <helpers:BehaviorCollection>
            <behaviors:AdvancedBehavior MyProperty="{Binding ElementName=DestinationFlyout}" />
        </helpers:BehaviorCollection>
    </helpers:XamlExtention.Behaviors>
</ListPickerFlyout>

<ListPickerFlyout x:Name="DestinationFlyout">
    <helpers:XamlExtention.Behaviors>
        <helpers:BehaviorCollection>
            <behaviors:AdvancedBehavior MyProperty="{Binding ElementName=SourceFlyout}" />
        </helpers:BehaviorCollection>
    </helpers:XamlExtention.Behaviors>
</ListPickerFlyout>
```

Comment: What is the final actual data for the attached property?

Comment: What is the actual definition for the `ListPickerFlyout`?

Comment: This is DependencyObject, control from Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls namespace, Windows Phone 8.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior `AdvancedBehavior` is not expecting to be bound to a `SourceFlyout` via `MyProperty`, you need to determine the actual data needed for `MyProperty` to work properly.